# Pass generated lambdas between different python versions

Tags: python, python-3.x, service, pickle, pypy

I have a service (CPython 3.6.8) that generates lambdas which I want to pass on to other services.

The problem is that some of the other services use a different version of python. It can be CPython 3.8.x or even pypy. So pickle will not work.

Is there a way to pass lambda functions between different python versions?

Comment: if its pure python just include the .py file in all repos ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley It's not a static function, it has context to it(closures) and can change. Just saving it won't work.